# Why doesn't the Firebase Storage UI ever display the thumbnail of my uploaded image?

Tags: python, firebase, python-requests, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

So I am trying to upload my data to firebase using python. Although my data is being pushed to the cloud and it's an image file of .png format. When I view my data in the cloud, it keeps on loading but never actually shows up. Although the size is identical to the size of the local image file. But I don't understand why It never displays the image. This wait bar keeps rotating.

Here's my code from the server-side (Python Code).

```
import firebase
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud.storage import client
import cv2
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import storage
cred = credentials.Certificate('certificate.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'storageBucket': 'test-cd462.appspot.com'
})

bucket = storage.bucket()
image_data=cv2.imread('1.png')
imageBlob = bucket.blob('Images.png')
blob.upload_from_string(
        image_data,
        content_type='image/png'
    )
print(imageBlob)
```

Here's the screenshot of what I am getting in my firebase window:
[image]

Please help me and let me know where have I gone wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possibly as simple as `imageBlob` ≠ `blob`?

Comment: Hmm... Pardon me but i didn't get you?  Can you explain a lil bit more?

Comment: You initialise a variable `imageBlob` but on the next line you use `blob.upload_from_string` rather than `imageBlob.upload_from_string`

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. One small help more please, so when I tried to upload data in this configuration, I got an error that my numpy array is supposed to be in bytes format.

Comment: My knowledge of Python is limited, but have you tried `image_data.tobytes()`?

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot I get it now. Just one small question too, when I run the code now, it shows me this error: could not be converted to bytes. As my image was in form of numpy array, but when I used conversion algorithm using this piece of code:
`success, encoded_image = cv2.imencode('.png', image_data)
image_data = encoded_image.tobytes()`
It gets successfully uploaded but again the same display doesn't appear at all like the older issue. Any idea with that?

Comment: Oh I see, yeah, I used the function .tobytes(). Still it doesn't load properly to the firebase console.

Comment: This is starting to sound like it should be asked as a separate question but have a look at this [GCP sample project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-python/blob/steps/3-binary-data/bookshelf/crud.py#L23-L42).

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks I'll try.